# why should we replace characters in string xml before parsing in java

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I had to go through a code like the following which is used before parsing the xml using SAX Parser.
But I couldn't get the explanations for some character replacements in the string xml.

```
public class basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlStr= some xml file;
        xmlStr= xmlStr.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
        xmlStr= xmlStr.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
       //Now some parsing mechanism using sax parser is continuing    
    }
}
```

Edit :
            As the symbol '+' means the sapces in terms of urls, the second line
            //xmlStr= xmlStr.replaceAll("\+", "%2B")
            was written for protecting symbol '+ from conversion of spaces.

```
        But still didn't understand the below line.
        //xmlStr= xmlStr.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})","%25");
        what is the significance of '?', '{}'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the parsing as such but with the application domain. Also, it seems to be a very ad hoc solution that maybe does not cover all possible cases.

Comment: are you trying to understand the meaning of those regex?

Comment: I want to know the functionality of the below statement.

xmlStr.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
What this is actually doing there. %25 is hexadecimal for %. Then why we are replacing those characters with percentile

Answer (score 1):

I guess that "xmlStr" here is the URI of an XML file rather than the content of the XML file, so the code is manipulating URIs rather than manipulating XML content. Manipulating URIs is often a messy process but this looks like ad-hoc code written to handle some particular need to repair badly formatted URIs, which shouldn't be necessary unless someone is passing in bad input.

Answer (score 0):

The line tries to replace a `%` sign with its encoding `%25` but only if it is not followed by two hexadecimal characters. Hence `%25` itself would not be encoded.

```
  xmlStr= xmlStr.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
```

- `(?! ...)` is negative look-ahead (not substituted), "there must not follow ...
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{2}` means two hexadecimal digits.
- `(? .... )` are not counted as group like other `(...)` which are $1, ... $9

By the way

```
xmlStr = xmlStr.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
```

could be written with a faster non-regular expression version:

```
xmlStr = xmlStr.replace("+", "%2B");
```